# I keep getting an underscore on the left side of images when I put them next to a button

Tags: html

So, I am trying to make an image button that when you click it, it takes you to a website, but I keep getting an underscore on the left side, how could I remove it? And also, do you think it is because I'm putting a button next to another button?

```html
          <a style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/clairo/">
          <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/clairopedia/images/4/4b/Clairo2020.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20201125212443">
        </a>
```

[image]

Comment: Remove all spacing between anchor tags and image tag: `<a href="abc"><img src="123"></a>`. Your anchor tag may be styled with underline or border.

Comment: You talk about a `button` but in the HTML you show has just an `a`. Besides that, the shown code does not reproduce the issue, you there have `text-decoration:none;` which removes that underline.

Comment: Your `style="text-decoration:none;"` should over-ride the CSS causing the underlining, Please update your question with your actual CSS causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `text-decoration: none;` for links in the head tag or the CSS file:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: The code shown by the OP has `<a style="text-decoration:none;"`, so `text-decoration: none` is already applied to that `a` element.

Comment: Ok I got it, finally, thank you guys